# IIS windows rewrite rules, frontend and backend separately

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I am using windows IIS server and i have two interfaces in a project, which is in PHP and it has two interfaces front-end and back-end.

1st URL is `localhost/controller/index.php/action`

2nd URL is `localhost/controller/admin/index.php/action`

Both front-end and the back-end has index.php, I want to remove the index.php from both directories.

Please suggest to remove index.php from both directories.